# How to apply CSS to td of particular table using Classname?

Tags: html, css

How to apply CSS to td of particular table using **Classname**? (Not ID or Name)

Following is HTML

```
<table class="pure-table ToBeApplied">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label>Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label>Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table class="pure-table NotToBeApplied>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label>Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label>Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to apply CSS say

```
td {padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;}
```

- i want to apply it on td's of table having **Classname**''ToBeApplied''.
- I do not want to write a class and write same on each td of table
- I do not want it to apply on td's of second table have **Classname**''NotToBeApplied''

How to modify HTML and CSS to achieve above?

Comment: You already post this question in which i've already answered.

Comment: Not. Please go through that post and this post. Secondly, i am always told by users to create new post when there is difference in questions instead of updating question later on.

Comment: @fatherazrael I really fail to see the difference, except for added fluff. Voting to close this as duplicate.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg
So do you think with same answers in another post; i can solve asked problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
table.ToBeApplied tbody tr td{
padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: It worked. But What if i do want to use only class name as suppose i need to applied same CSS elsewhere i need to rewrite it. Isn't possibility of using class name and slight modification to HTML help?

Comment: This css is only applied to tables with the class `.ToBeApplied`. If you want the use other style with the same class on the table, you should add another class and respectives rules which will break the `.ToBeApplied` class. Ex: `table.ToBeApplied.NotToBeApplied tbody tr td`

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`.ToBeApplied td {padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
table.pure-table.ToBeApplied td{
  padding-top:0px; 
  padding-bottom:0px;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> i want to apply it on td's of table having Classname''ToBeApplied''.

Use:

```
.ToBeApplied td { ... }
```

> I do not want to write a class and write same on each td of table

You don't need to, the code above will apply to all cells in `table.ToBeApplied`

> I do not want it to apply on td's of second table have Classname''NotToBeApplied''

It won't.

Comment: It does not work. CHeck fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/o2dfqrkg/

Comment: @fatherazrael, sure it does. CSS is a cascading stylesheet, meaning it reads from top to bottom. So first you apply a padding 0 to the `.ToBeApplied` table, but after that you a apply a padding to the `.pure-table` which is the same (first) table. Change the order and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/o2dfqrkg/2/